# Store latest state of data on S3 using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-emr, delta-lake

I am working on Spark-EMR job. My requirement is to read data from s3 every hour, do the same flatten transformation, and save the latest state of data based on machine-id. I can get the same machine-id data in the next hour also so I need to maintain the latest state of that machine. As we know data s3 is not a database and it does not support update operation. So I created an s3 partition based on machine-id.

```
       df
      .repartition($"machineid")
      .write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .partitionBy("machineid")
      .parquet("s3a://bucket...")
```

when the job reads the same machine data in the next run, the job overwrites only that specific machine-id partition using this property `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic`. Everything is working fine. The only issue that I faced is each partition contains a few KB files. And also partitions count goes beyond 30K which creates a performance issue in Athena

I read somewhere about delta-lake. Delta Lake provides ACID transactions, scalable metadata handling, and unifies streaming and batch data processing. So I am planning to move parquet output to delta output.

My questions are -

1. What is the best way to upsert in s3 using spark? Partition by that unique column or is there any other way to solve this problem?
2. Should I use the same partitioning structure (machine-id) Or save data without partition on s3. Delta formate update operation will take care of the latest state of the machine.
3. If machine-id partition structure is correct then will it not cause performance issues when partitions count go beyond 50K

Comment: is machineid an index of your query? if yes, then you can add it to the partition index of the athena. See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/big-data/improve-amazon-athena-query-performance-using-aws-glue-data-catalog-partition-indexes/)

Comment: No, I used machineid as the partition. So that I can overwrite this partition if case same machineid data comes in the next run.

Comment: do you need the previous hours data ie historical data or just want the latest hour data and can delete the previous hours data?

Comment: Do not care about old data. I need to maintain the latest state of machine data that has a unique key machine-id. Means machine-id wise I need latest data.